# Capture image and save it on the internal storage

Tags: android, image, camera, internal-storage

I'm trying to take a picture, save it on the internal storage and then show it in  a imageview (cause i can't access internal storage and look for the image).

Taking the picture seems to work but loading the image to the imageview with the uri isn't working
(the uri returned by the intent is: "file:/data/user/0/com.packagename/filesfoldername/filename"). imageview stays empty.

```
private static String date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy").format(new Date());
private File sessionDirectory=null;
private ImageView imgView;
private Uri HelpUri;

@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Uri= " + HelpUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error Taking Photo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}


//Method creates an Intent to the camera - Capture an Image and save it//
private void openCamera(String Pose) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File ImageFile = null;
        try {
            ImageFile = createImageFile(Pose);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Something for errors..
        }

        if (ImageFile != null) {
            Uri ImageURI = android.net.Uri.parse(ImageFile.toURI().toString());
            HelpUri = ImageURI;
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, ImageURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Problem Accessing Internal Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Methods returns a File for the image file created on the internal storage//
private File createImageFile(String Pose) throws IOException {
    if(sessionDirectory==null)
        createSessionFolder();

    if(sessionDirectory!=null) {    //Succeed creating/finding the session directory
        return File.createTempFile(
                Pose,      /* prefix */
                ".jpg",             /* suffix */
                sessionDirectory    /* directory */
        );
    }
    else
        return null;
}

//Method creates the session directory - update the field if existed, creates it if not//
private void createSessionFolder() {
    sessionDirectory = new File(getFilesDir()+"Session_"+date);
    if (!sessionDirectory.exists())
        if(!sessionDirectory.mkdirs())  //Tried to create the directory buy failed
            sessionDirectory = null;
}
```

I would be greatfull if anyone can help.

Thank you very much

Comment: Third-party apps cannot write to your app's portion of internal storage.

Comment: `the uri returned by the intent is: "file:/data/user/0/com.packagename/filesfoldername/filename"` Impossible. It would be "file:///data/user/0/com.packagename/filesfoldername/filename" instead. And it is NOT returned by the intent.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it was my mistake..this is the uri created by the process to detect the directory and filename...

Answer (score -2):

```
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private String picture_directory = "/picturedir/";


    public void openCamera(Context context) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null){
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                Uri urifromFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);

                 takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    urifromFile);
                context.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
         // Create an image file name
         String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
         String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
         File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+picture_directory);
         storageDir.mkdirs();

         image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
         );

         return image;
    }
```

Add provider path to res/xml folder. And declare it on AndroidManifest.xml. More information on here [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
 </paths>


 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

Also do not forget to get permission from user.

```
   public void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need permissions for internal storage. And if you use external storage you dont need a file provider. Well not below 7.0.

Comment: @iravul why you used Environment.getExternal...? i want to save the image on the internal storage. what should replace it?